Can I use condition's variable in the error_message of a Terraform variable validation?
tl;dr: I want to use the current value of a runtime variable created in the condition part of a variable validation, to give more details about the error.
I am looking for a way to improve my error_message for variable validation in my Terraform project.
Say I have 2 variable:

availabilityzones gives the list of AZ my module/project can use.
workloads defines some workload to start for this module/project can use.

Workloads have an AMI (not relevant here) and are given a number of AZ they can use (span): az_count.
My workloads variable has a validation to make sure the number of AZ is consistent with the size of availabilityzones:
condition = alltrue([
  for workload_name, workload in var.workloads :
    1 <= workload.az_count && workload.az_count <= length(var.availabilityzones)
])

Validation works and can detect too large az_count, but I would like to tell the user which workload caused the issue, so I tried to use the workload_name variable (the one from the condition) in the error_message:
error_message = "For a workload, the AZ count must be between `1` and the number of configured AZ (both inclusive). Workload \"${workload_name}\" has: ${tonumber(workload.az_count)}"

But it fails:
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on …/variables.tf line 42, in variable "workloads":
│  129:     error_message = "For a workload, the AZ count must be between `1` and the number of configured AZ (both inclusive). Workload \"${workload_name}\" has: ${tonumber(workload.az_count)}"
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

I am guessing the context from condition is lost once validation has detected an error, and it not passed to error_message's context?
Is there a workaround?
One I can think of would be repeating the test in error_message to re-find the invalid value, but this would always find/display the first invalid value, even if multiple workloads are incorrect.
Full code below:
variable "availabilityzones" {
  description = "The availability zones (AZs) to use."
  default = [
    "eu-west-1a",
    "eu-west-1b",
    "eu-west-1c",
  ]
  type = set(string)
}

variable "workloads" {
  default = {
    workload_foo = {
      az_count = 1
      ami = "ami-061ff9349538cd3f1"
    }
    workload_bar = {
      az_count = 2
      ami = "ami-0e309138dd3e25b2e"
    }
    workload_bad = {
      az_count = 4 # ⟽ Too many AZ here
      ami = "ami-040a86d5d7bf29267"
    }
  }
  type = map(object({
      # How many AZ to use?
      az_count = number

      # Which AMI should the workload use?
      ami = string
    }))

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for workload_name, workload in var.workloads :
        1 <= workload.az_count && workload.az_count <= length(var.availabilityzones)
    ])
    error_message = "For a workload, the AZ count must be between `1` and the number of configured AZ (both inclusive). Workload \"${workload_name}\" has: ${tonumber(workload.az_count)}"
  }
}


I opened an issue on the Terraform project's issue tracker: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/35775

I don't think you'll be able to use a validation block for this given that within them you can only refer to the variable context.
You can however achieve the desired behavior with a check block:
variable "availabilityzones" {
  description = "The availability zones (AZs) to use."
  default = [
    "eu-west-1a",
    "eu-west-1b",
    "eu-west-1c",
  ]
  type = set(string)
}

variable "workloads" {
  default = {
    workload_foo = {
      az_count = 1
      ami      = "ami-061ff9349538cd3f1"
    }
    workload_bar = {
      az_count = 2
      ami      = "ami-0e309138dd3e25b2e"
    }
    workload_bad = {
      az_count = 4 # ⟽ Too many AZ here
      ami      = "ami-040a86d5d7bf29267"
    }
  }
  type = map(object({
    # How many AZ to use?
    az_count = number

    # Which AMI should the workload use?
    ami = string
  }))

}

locals {
  workflow_check = {
    for workload_name, workload in var.workloads :
    workload_name => [1 <= workload.az_count && workload.az_count <= length(var.availabilityzones), workload.az_count]
  }
  invalid_workflow = {for k,v in local.workflow_check : k => tostring(v[1]) if v[0] == false}
}

check "validate_variables" {
  assert {
    condition = local.invalid_workflow == {}
    error_message = local.invalid_workflow == {} ? "" : "For a workload, the AZ count must be between `1` and the number of configured AZ (both inclusive). Workload \"${keys(local.invalid_workflow)[0]}\" has: ${tonumber(values(local.invalid_workflow)[0])}"
  }
}

$ terraform plan
╷
│ Warning: Check block assertion failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 49, in check "validate_variables":
│   49:     condition = local.invalid_workflow == {}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.invalid_workflow is object with 1 attribute "workload_bad"
│ 
│ For a workload, the AZ count must be between `1` and the number of configured AZ (both inclusive). Workload "workload_bad" has: 4
╵

you can adapt this so that in the case that there are multiple workloads that fail the check the error message includes them all.

Too bad we can't use the native validation block of variable for this, but I now have a workaround. Thank you.
